# containers with images of different sizes; container width won't go past the image width

Tags: html, css

I have divs with images in them stacked horizontally side by side of each other.  Images are of different widths and heights.

If I make the container width's *smaller* than the images, all the divs are uniform nicely.

But if I make the width of the container *bigger* than the images, the div/container width just seems to stop at the size of the image and refuse to get any bigger.  What am I doing wrong or am I misunderstanding anything?  I'm still learning my HTML and CSS thank you

PS - I don't want to use `background: url(...)` because I need my image URLs to be dynamic.  Unless this is the only way?

```css
.test__container {
  width: 800px;
}

.test__img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test__container">
  <img class="test__img" src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/' />
  <h1 class="test__name">Davy Crocket</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? You should add `width: 100%` for the image to make it responsive

Comment: @ITgoldman just tried but isn't working unfortunately

Comment: This is a scss file that you are compiling to css right

Comment: @ITgoldman yes it is.  when i inspect, i see the containers as 800px, but the visually the containers are next to each other and NOT 800px.  they're just side by side perfectly

Comment: Oh so maybe they are inside a container with display:flex that makes it kind of ignore the width. But the image should have stretch to width 100%

Comment: @ITgoldman hm okay i was messing with flexbox but didn't realize flexbox ignores width.  good to know

Comment: @ITgoldman you're right.  the parent was a flexbox.  i didn't realize it changes the width of its children.  i'm assuming to fix this i have to mess with grow/shrink/basis.  submit an answer and i'll give you credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible they are inside a flex container (that has `display:flex`). That makes it treat `width` property of children differently.

When you create a flex container (display: flex or display: inline-flex), it comes with several default settings. Among them are:... [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818560/3807365)
(specifically it forces items to stay on one line [no matter the count])

Comment: are you in IT at Goldman Sachs?

Comment: Not at all it's my name kind of

Answer (score 1):

Give the images a width of `100%`. This will make them as wide as their parent, not as wide as their native size.

```scss
&__img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Update** (based on added context): if the parent container has a display property of `flex`, one has to set `min-width` to `100%` on the image. Note: `flex-wrap: wrap` should also be set on parent, to prevent siblings from creating a horizontal scrollbar on parent.
An alternative solution is to give the image `flex-basis` of `100%` and `flex-shrink` of `0`.
However, flex calculation is dependent on several other CSS attributes of the image as well as on CSS attributes and content of siblings and of parent elements. The safest option for flex remains `min-width`, as it trumps the result of flex calculation (basically the flex calculation starts from the given `min-width` and distributes the remaining space, if any, to the flexible siblings).

Comment: just tried it but not working for whatever reason.  when i inspect in the console, the width is 800px correctly, but the image isn't stretching

Comment: Please provide a *runnable* [mcve]. You're probably missing a detail. This can't be fixed without inspecting.

Comment: the images are coming from internal code i wish i could share.  damn ty regardless

Comment: See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/9exogard/). Obviously, i changed `className` to `class` and just used a placeholder `src`. You're probably missing a dot somewhere :). As I said, can't help without eyes on it. What you share doesn't need to be react. Make it dumb and use some random src's, as long as they're valid. This is CSS related, not react related, so remove React from equation.

Comment: thank i'll mess with this jsfiddle and see if i can come up with the situation i'm coming across

Comment: okay so i figured out the parent of these containers is a flexbox, i didn't realize it would remove the width of its children though.  is that accurate?

Comment: it depends.  see the answers below. Both are correct

Comment: @user, it doesn't *remove* the width. It just doesn't consider it. In that case, you want to set the `flex-basis` to `100%` and it will work. Or, alternatively set `min-width` to `100%`.

Comment: @tao after watching some youtube videos you're correct.  it's definitely the flex-basis ty

Answer (score 0):

as you can see from the snippet below wrapping your code in a flexbox container doesn't change anything by itself.  There most be either additional css or something else going on.

I edited your original post. You will get help faster if you post snippets here instead  of providing a link to js fiddle.

```css
.test__container {
    width: 800px;
  }
.test__img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#container{
display:flex;}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class="test__container">
    <img class="test__img" src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/' />
    <h1 class="test__name">Davy Crocket</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="test__container">
  <img class="test__img" src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/' />
  <h1 class="test__name">Davy Crocket</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .page {
      width: 500px;
    }
    
    .container {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    img {
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://news.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/20220225_wondering_dog-2048x1366.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://www.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/styles/full_2x/public/images/2022/02/KOA_Nassau_2697x1517.jpg?itok=Hy5eTACi" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```