# flex container makes no space for an icon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying a tutorial and am currently stuck. My problem is that the search icon in my button is messing up and overlapping instead of sitting nicely in the center. Tried a bunch of CSS fixes, but no luck.

The Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIYQR-Ybrn4&list=PLjwm_8O3suyOgDS_Z8AWbbq3zpCmR-WE9

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #222;
}

.card {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 470px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #00feba, #5b548a);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 40px 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  color: #555;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.search button {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search button img {
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City Name" spellcheck="false">
      <button><img src="images/search.png"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

It should look like this:
[image]

but it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What browser/OS are you seeing your second screenshot on?

Comment: Firefox and Windows

Comment: Does the demo above accurately show your problem? Icons are often fonts applied to pseudo-elements, so you may need to explicitly set a size on the button. Please revise to show the problem.

Comment: But the Button has a width and a heigth -> 60px both

Comment: I'm using Firefox 119.0.1 (32-bit) on Windows 10 22H2 and I don't see the issue. Of course, I don't see the image either, since that image doesn't exist on Stack Overflow's server.

Comment: Try setting `aspect-ratio: 1` on the button.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this answer to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818560/20913924), when you apply `display: flex;` to an element, there are default properties that are set on the element. One of these properties is [`flex-shrink: 1;`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-shrink), which tells each flex item to shrink to fit within the flex container. You can prevent your button from shrinking by setting `flex-shrink: 0;` on it.

```
.search button {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Here is a working snippet:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #222;
}

.card {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 470px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #00feba, #5b548a);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 40px 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  color: #555;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.search button {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.search button img {
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City Name" spellcheck="false">
      <button><img src="images/search.png"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped! But the container was to small after all so i needed to make him larger. I wonder why... i took the same px like the tutorial.

Comment: Yeah I noticed on smaller screens it overflows to the right. You could take a look into using (media queries)[https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp] to change the padding, size, etc. when on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Search icon needs flex-grow and flex-shrink set to 0. And the card needs to have min width set.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #222;
}

.card {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 470px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #00feba, #5b548a);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 40px 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.search input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  color: #555;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.search button {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #ebfffc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search button img {
  width: 16px;
}


/* rules to solve the issues */

.search button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.search input {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.card {
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City Name" spellcheck="false">
      <button><img src="images/search.png"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! fit-content solved all my Problems. Super nice. Do i really need flex 1 1 auto and flex 0 0 auto? they didnt do anything so i wonder what they do.

Comment: @Benji228 With explicit width set on search button. We don't need them with `fit-content`. :)